# How to Prevent Keyboard appearing for EditText that is not enabled

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

My activity has an `EditText` which is supposedly not editable until user clicks on edit button for the screen.

I did `edit.setEnabled(false)` but still a keyboard appears for the user and values can be added to the `EditText` in the screen via the keyboard even though the screen might look a bit greyed out.  What else do I have to do to prevent editing of the `EditText` until user has specifically pushed an edit button.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 28):

Attention that `setEditable` is depecrated.

You can use :

```
setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
```

To turn keyboard on.

```
setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL)
```

To turn keyboard off.

Comment: @MoJo Probably because barcodereader was last seen in :Jun 13 '11 at 11:07 :)

Comment: I still want my cursor there, but not the keyboard -what then?

Answer (score 2):

To make EditText Write Only and not have the keyboard show up I use these two commends within the .xml layout file.

```
        android:editable="false"
        android:inputType="none"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `setEditable(false)` on your EditText.

Set it back to true when you want someone to be able to type in it.

Comment: I looked for that too but I don't think it has a setEditable  there is a setEditableFactory ....

Answer (score 1):

in your layout file add the attribute to your EditText

`android:editable="false"`

Answer (score 1):

In API level 21, a function has been added to EditText, namely

```
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(boolean show);
```

This is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use edittext.setInputType(0); in your java file.

Comment: Well that just disables it.  Please discuss the whole issue, how would you re-enable it.

Comment: The note I have reviewed indicate that setting back to 1 does not re-enable it.