# Dialog shows twice

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I'm making an dialog box on my `EditText`, so when I touch the `EditText`, the box will show (setOntouchListener). The problem is: when I touch the `EditText`, the box is shown twice (when I click dismiss button in the box, the second box shows and the content of the box is exactly the same)

```
FoodText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override           
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customfoodinput);
        dialog.setTitle("Insert your Food");

        spinner1 = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_foodTime);            
        spinner2 = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_foodType);

        foodtimeArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(foodtimeArray);

        foodtypeArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(foodtypeArray);

        Button btntampung = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_inputfood);

        btntampung.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Object item = spinner1.getSelectedItem();
                String dataspinner = item.toString();

                Object item2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem();
                String dataspinner2 = item2.toString();

                dialog.dismiss();
                FoodText.setText(dataspinner + "; " + dataspinner2);

            }
        });

        dialog.show();

        return false;           
    }
});
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: onTouch is called for every single touch event. putting your finger on the screen is a touch, releasing is another, dragging can be another as well. that's at least 2 dialogs.

Comment: i see, so what i must do in order to make the box only show once?

Comment: take a look at the content of the touch event and filter some actions. or disable you touch area (by removing the listener or disabling the touch on the widget) in the first touch event

Comment: can you show me how? i'm sorry for too much asking, I'm new in android, thank you for your concern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that a touch event detects more interaction than what you want. It detects the press and the release, so it is called two times. You want to detect only the press you can check the type of the event in your touchListener using an if (`if(arg1.getAction();  == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)`):

```
FoodText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            showDialog();

        return false;
   }
});
```

If you want a simpler solution you can replace your `onTouchListener` for an `onClickListener`.

Instead of setting `setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()` and overriding `public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)` replace those two line of code by:

```
FoodText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});
```

If you want to ignore the keyboard try to disable it using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066095/how-to-prevent-keyboard-appearing-for-edittext-that-is-not-enabled/6216789#6216789).

Comment: it's worked, ive change it with (if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to use onClickListener!

if u put the finger on the screen and move it around you'll see several boxes coming up for each new position of your finger.

Comment: it work, but i must click the edittext twice, because the first time when i click the box, the virtual keyboard pop up, and the second time i click, the dialog box appear, do you know how i can make the box appear at the first time click?

Comment: Didn't notice I was adding an answer with an existent answer (10 minutes ago? :/ meh...)
Anyway, edited my answer so you can have a solution for your keyboard.