# How to prevent user from entering data in Edittext and enable Edittext to get data only from Dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-edittext

My requirement is that when user clicks on edittext, a dialog should pop up enabling the user to select one of the values from lit.

The above portion has been accomplished.

I do not want user to enter/edit any other value than values given in list in dialog. I want user to select only the values given in list in dialog.

I am facing the problem in accomplishing this part.

Please help.Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pawan

Comment: Use a spinner(drop down list) instead of edittext according to your requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066095/how-to-prevent-keyboard-appearing-for-edittext-that-is-not-enabled?rq=1

Comment: Can it not be done via EditText?

Comment: @Softcoder I will try the solution given in link and will let u know.Thanks

Comment: instead of edittext take one textview and add a spinner to it , when clicking on spinner list item change texview text(using settext) to spinner item value.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, it would be nice to accept it (check mark on the left of my answer) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9724815/4428462).

From the link:

> Add `android:focusable="false"` to your EditText. And set `OnClickListener` to that EditText. The click on that Edittext triggers the `onClick()` method but it can't be edited.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting inputtype of EditText to **null**?

Programatically:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

XML:

```
android:inputType="none"
```

The `edtText.setText(String)` method will still work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Setting android:focusable="false" worked for me. It will not enable user to edit data and force him to select from list in dialog.

Thanks @JonasCz for answer